# Log nodeJS version

Tags: node.js

I know I can check the node version in my path with

```
node -v
```

But I have a system that's not run from that path and I want to check which node version it's using. Something like `console.log(node.version)` would be ideal

Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
console.log(process.version);
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: The provided answer works fine. If you're looking for variants or further properties of the process object, look at  https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_version  resp. at https://nodejs.org/en/docs/ in general for the appropriate API version.